# ForEach(0...5,id: \.self) { n in --what is the scope of "n"?

Tags: swiftui

See the following TestView. When I clicked "Button 5", I see the alert shows "**Button 0 clicked**".

```
struct TestView: View {
   @State var showAlert = false
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
            Button(action: {
               self.showAlert.toggle()
            }) {
               Text("Button \(n)")
            }
            .padding(20)
            .border(Color.green, width: 4)
            .padding(8)
            .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert) {
               Alert(title: Text("Button \(n) clicked"))
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Regardless of which button I click, the alert always show **"Button 0 clicked"**. I was expecting each button should show its own button index. Wondering why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is happening because everything in your TestView re-renders while **state** variable changes. So your alert is displaying only for the first loop iteration. The decision is to change other variable, which should contain clicked button index:

```
struct TextView: View {
    @State var showAlert = false
    @State var clickedButtonIndex = 0
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
          ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
             Button(action: {
                self.showAlert.toggle()
                self.clickedButtonIndex = n
             }) {
                Text("Button \(n)")
             }
             .padding(20)
             .border(Color.green, width: 4)
             .padding(8)
             .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Button \(self.clickedButtonIndex) clicked"))
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

And you'll have this result:
[image]